# Averages of Column values placed into either its own column, or workflow variable

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, calculated-column, average

I've researched this one - and while I have found many helpful articles CLOSE to it, nothing hits exactly what I'm needing.

I'm trying to populate either a variable in a workflow OR a column with the averages of all the numbers in an existing column  (i.e. - multiple list items).  I can't use the "total", etc, at the top (or bottom) of the page.  This must be a real value I can work with and display.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you can not use the "total"?

You can create a Number (1, 1.0, 100)type column and modify view-> in total section, choose "average" for the number column:

[image]

Comment: The column I'm trying to average is a Calculated Column, and won't show up in Totals.

Comment: Plus, I want to be able to pull that value and use it.  Is there a way to do this, Lisa?